# How do i copy a file name with any extention?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
private void GetHostsFile()
        {
            string Windows_95_98_Me = @"c:\windows\hosts";
            string Windows_NT_2000_XP_Pro = @"c:\winnt\system32\drivers\etc\hosts";
            string Windows_XP_Home = @"c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts";
            string Windows8 = @"C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts";

            string fileName = "hosts";

            if (Directory.Exists(Windows_95_98_Me))
            {
                File.Copy(test1,test2, true);
            }
        }
```

I want to copy the file "hosts" to a new location.
But sometimes the file can be only hosts or hosts.txt so i want to cover all options and just copy something like host*.*

How can i do it instead of test1 and test2 ?

Comment: Can you do the copy with a system call?  That would (easily) allow for * notation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# copying multiple files with wildcards and keeping file names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835578/c-sharp-copying-multiple-files-with-wildcards-and-keeping-file-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) with the search patern something like "hosts*.*" and then copy all the files found to another directory.

Something like

```
string sourceDirectory = @"D:\";
string destinationDirectory = @"D:\Test";
List<string> fileNames = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "hosts*.*"));

for (int iFile = 0; iFile < fileNames.Count; iFile++)
{
    string fileName = fileNames[iFile];
    File.Copy(fileName, Path.Combine(destinationDirectory,Path.GetFileName(fileName)));
}
```

See also

[Path.Combine Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx)

[Path.GetFileName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Windows_95_98_Me, "host*.*");

foreach (string s in files) {
    System.IO.File.Copy(s, System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s)), true);
}
```