# Change VBScript script code to C#:

Tags: c#, vbscript

I have following code written in VBScript Script. I need to change it to c#.

```
Set objFileCopy = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const OverwriteExisting = True
strReNameFileName = "\\sqlapps\Applications\CCMS$\CCMS_Daily_Refresh\Archive_NIA\"
strMoveFrom = "\\sqlapps\Applications\CCMS$\CCMS_Daily_Refresh\NIA_Auth_Radiolog_Files\SFTP_IN\ITRANS.*"

objFileCopy.CopyFile strMoveFrom, strReNameFileName, OverwriteExisting.
```

**C# code i have written**

```
strReNameFileName = @"\\devsqlapps2\Applications\CCMS$\CCMS_Daily_Refresh\Archive_NIA\";
strMoveFrom = @"\\devsqlapps2\Applications\CCMS$\CCMS_Daily_Refresh\NIA_Auth_Radiolog_Files\SFTP_IN\ITRANS.*";
File.Copy(strMoveFrom, strReNameFileName, true);
```

Is the code i have written correct?? . It says

> *File path character is illegal*

both `strReNameFileName` and `strMoveFrom` file path exist in a system

Comment: Wildcards are not supported by `File.Copy()`, see [C# copying multiple files with wildcards and keeping file names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835578/c-sharp-copying-multiple-files-with-wildcards-and-keeping-file-names)

Comment: The first isn't a file name, its a file path

Comment: Hi alex K, Actually i have five file inside a strMovefrom filepath.

Comment: strMoveFrom = @"\\devsqlapps2\Applications\CCMS$\CCMS_Daily_Refresh\NIA_Auth_Radiolog_Files\SFTP_IN\ITRANS.*"; ;  ** Does  ITRANS.* **  means all the file with file name ITRANS or it also refer to file name like ITRANS_CS. ??

Comment: You cannot use *wildcards* (`*`) - You must provide a full file name for the source and destination to `File.Copy()`